# Sleeping between Isha and Tahajjud

Tags: salat, practical-islam, tahajjud

If I sleep after praying maghrib (because of my busy schedule) and wake up at night, can I pray Isha and Tahajjud together?

I usually try to sleep between Isha and Tahajjud but for the last few days my routine has been a bit disturbed due to busy schedule. I sometimes can't hold up and sleep right after praying maghrib.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make the ‘Isha prayer before midnight,  then there is no harm in combining it with tahajjud prayer. As a matter of fact, it is preferable to delay ‘Isha prayer a bit later up until midnight.